# Promotions magento - how make it works

Tags: promotions, magento-1.9

Ok. Thats what i want to do:

If somebody bought 1 product from Category_1, recive free shipping.
If somebody bought 2 products from Category_1, recive 10USD discount and free shipping.
If somebody bought 3 products from Category_1, recive 30USD discount and free shipping.
...
If somebody bought 1 product from Category_1, and 1 product from Category 2, no discount.
If somebody bought 2 products from Category_1, and 1 product from Category 2, 10 USD discount.
If somebody bought 3 products from Category_1, and 1 productfrom Category 2, 20USD discount.
...
If somebody bought 1 product from Category_1, and 2 producst from Category 2, 10USD discount.

SOmething like that. How i can operate that thing?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps for the first case :

1. Go to backend -> Promotions -> Shopping cart rules -> Add new rule

[image]

[image]

[image]

In the second picture I have assigned category id as 3. You assign ID of your Category_1

For second case : in the third step change the Discount Amount as 10

For third case : in the third step change the Discount Amount as 30